# better performance for algorithm

Tags: c#

I have something like this:

```
using (SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(query, c))
            {
                // 3
                // Use DataAdapter to fill DataTable
                DataTable t = new DataTable();
                a.Fill(t);

                string txt = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < t.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    txt += "\n" + t.Rows[i][0] + "\t" + t.Rows[i][1] + "\t" + t.Rows[i][2] + "\t" + t.Rows[i][3] + "\t" + t.Rows[i][4] + "\t" + t.Rows[i][5] + "\t" + t.Rows[i][6] + "\t" + t.Rows[i][7] + "\t" + t.Rows[i][8] + "\t" + t.Rows[i][9] + "\t" + t.Rows[i][10] + "\t" + t.Rows[i][11] + "\t" + t.Rows[i][12] + "\t" + t.Rows[i][13] + "\t" + t.Rows[i][14] + "\t" + t.Rows[i][15] + "\t" + t.Rows[i][16] + "\t" + t.Rows[i][17] + "\t" + t.Rows[i][18] + "\t" + t.Rows[i][19];
                }


            }
```

I need this tabs between columns to generate txt file later.
Problem is that t.Rows.Count = 600000 and this loop works 9 hours.
Any ideas how to make this faster?

Regards
kazik

Comment: Is your environment multi-core?  This seems like an easily parallelized operation.  Also, why not directly write to a file stream instead of generating a large string first?

Comment: You might want to try building the result using pure SQL. It may be faster than pushing all the data through to the C# side for processing. Also, failing that, instead of filling a datatable and then iterating, you could [iterate directly over an IDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.100).aspx) (streaming in the data as needed).

Comment: You may also want to write directly into file, and not hold the data in memory.

Answer (score 8):

Use a `StringBuilder` instead of concatenating your strings.

```
            string txt = "";
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < t.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(t.Rows[i][0]); 
                sb.Append("\t");
                sb.Append(t.Rows[i][1]);
                //and so on...
           }
           string txt = sb.ToString();
```

Adding a string to another string (by assigning it back again) takes effort relative to the length of the *combined string* - this gets very costly fast for large strings  - it is a [Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter%27s_algorithm). Using a `StringBuilder` avoids this since no new string have to be created every time you add a new string to its content.

I have to question though why you keep all of this data in memory just to write it out to a file - you should switch to a model that allows you to generate line by line of the text content, I would suggest using a data reader instead and method that yields text lines, e.g.:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GenerateTextOutput()
{
   //...
   //using SqlDataReader instead
   while(reader.Read())
   {
     //assemble string for next row
     string txt = "...";
     yield return txt;
   }
}
```

Then you can just write this output to disk:

```
File.WriteAllLines("foo.txt", GenerateTextOutput());
```

Comment: Also, if you can estimate the size of the data, initialize the `StringBuilder` with that size.

Answer (score 4):

Use StringBuilder. You can find examples everywhere on the web.

Comment: this article shows that concatenation is faster then StringBuilder: http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2010/05/10/c-string-compares-and-concatenations.aspx

Comment: It's not continuously concatenating each result together into one giant string as you are.

Comment: When the number of items is constant, this is true. If not, it's not. This is a common mistake btw: Resharper eroneously uses StringBuilder in generated ToString() methods although the number of items is constant. The C# compiler does this right in anonymous type ToString().

Comment: @usr: I've never heard of that before. Why does it matter if the number of items is constant?

Comment: Because you can statically size a holding array for the parts. You don't need to grow it. From that array you can also determine the final string size in a single cheap pass over it. You can then allocate the target string to the perfect size. (Look at string.Concat in Reflector).

Answer (score 2):

Others mentioned `StringBuilder`, and they are correct. However, note that in .NET 4 StringBuilder became more efficient, avoiding reallocations and memory copying altogether. If you're using a previous version of .NET, you will get worse performance. It will still beat what you're doing.

I wonder what you're doing with `txt` after it's ready. You might want to avoid storing the string in memory altogether, and write it directly to a file (I don't believe you're showing your users 600,000 lines...)

Answer (score 0):

`StringBuilder` has already been mentioned by others and should provide significant benefit.

Do you *really* need to keep the entire text in memory with 600K rows? You can speed this up a lot by directly writing to the file.

And for that many iterations, assigning Rows[i] to a variable might also provide some extra spped-up.